# Are there any themes for Windows 2003 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, themes

Are there any themes for Windows 2003?

I am primarily looking for official themes from Microsoft although I would not mind hearing about unofficial themes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, the only themes available to Server 2003 are the same as Windows XPs. Simply go into the Services Manager and start the "Themes" service, and set it to auto-run, or type this into a command prompt with administrative permissions:

```
sc config Themes start=auto
sc start Themes
```

Unofficially, there are plenty of ways people have managed to jack in new themes.

**I don't recommend this part:**

You can install your own themes from various websites, such as http://customize.org/xpthemes. XP's and Server 2003's shell are similar enough that XP themes *might* work in Server 2003 - or it might completely tank it. Try at your own risk.